# How to fix WebKit crash on objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, firebase

I try to fix an error on firebase.

My sources are based on objective-c, and "webkit" is a problem in my code

I try and try to find what is cause of it, but I can't. Because these errors appears in a different places but same error.

```
stack trace : com.apple.main-thread
**EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000028**
keyboard_arrow_up
arrow_right 0
WebKit
WebKit::ProcessThrottler::setAssertionType(WebKit::ProcessAssertionType) + 544
```

I know it has only few clues for finding. Sorry.

My codes have a lot of request datas to Server and response from Server on mainthread.

I expect it occurs  this problem but I'm not sure.

Thanks.

full call stack

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  WebKit                         0x199361fcc WebKit::ProcessThrottler::setAssertionType(WebKit::ProcessAssertionType) + 544
1  WebKit                         0x199361fb4 WebKit::ProcessThrottler::setAssertionType(WebKit::ProcessAssertionType) + 520
2  WebKit                         0x199362484 WebKit::ProcessThrottler::sendPrepareToSuspendIPC(WebKit::IsSuspensionImminent) + 596
3  WebKit                         0x199367620 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WebKit::ProcessThrottler::setAssertionType(WebKit::ProcessAssertionType)::$_1, void>::call() + 144
4  WebKit                         0x199435e40 -[WKProcessAssertionBackgroundTaskManager _notifyAssertionsOfImminentSuspension] + 436
5  WebKit                         0x1994364b0 -[WKProcessAssertionBackgroundTaskManager _handleBackgroundTaskExpirationOnMainThread] + 312
6  JavaScriptCore                 0x197034278 WTF::Detail::CallableWrapper<WTF::callOnMainAndWait(WTF::Function<void ()>&&, WTF::MainStyle)::$_0, void>::call() + 48
7  JavaScriptCore                 0x197049324 WTF::RunLoop::performWork() + 484
8  JavaScriptCore                 0x197049f24 WTF::RunLoop::performWork(void*) + 36
9  CoreFoundation                 0x18cfdb81c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
10 CoreFoundation                 0x18cfdb718 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208
11 CoreFoundation                 0x18cfdaa28 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268
12 CoreFoundation                 0x18cfd4d20 __CFRunLoopRun + 824
13 CoreFoundation                 0x18cfd44bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
14 GraphicsServices               0x1a3ae6820 GSEventRunModal + 164
15 UIKitCore                      0x18f981164 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072
16 UIKitCore                      0x18f986840 UIApplicationMain + 168
17 MyApp                      0x10235f3d0 main + 29 (main.m:29)
18 libdyld.dylib                  0x18cc9be40 start + 4
```

Comment: is it possible to full call stack? try to add an exception breakpoint to find the trigger of the crash. The error you mentioned is a generic error.

Comment: Sorry, I can't add exception breakpoint. Because the crash point is placed randomly everytimes. So I can't reproduce error and only see it on Firebase